# Copy a dropdown list to another cell

Tags: excel, vba

How to copy a dropdown list with all its items to another cell by using VBA? I know it can be done by putting all the items into an array and then create a new dropdown list. But is there a way to copy directly?

Comment: Drop down list as in validation list? If that is the case, you can simply copy and paste validation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using drop down list then you can simply copy and paste the cell containing it
using

`Selection.Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste`

This doesnt just apply to validation lists as long as the combo box is contained within a cell e.g.[image]

Hope this helps